# MS Office 2011 Word printing range of pages fails

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office

I tried to print pages 7-8 and 11-14 of a 14 page document. Word decided it was going to print the whole document. No matter what settings I tried; whole document. Except that you can successfully print "current page".

I have seen this issue complained about for about 2 years, but did not find any solution. Only that the problem was "intermittent" and "fixed itself."

Is there any better wisdom than the workaround of printing one page at a time?

In addition, during the attempts to use the different page range settings, I saw the the preview would occasionally report the document had 28 pages. And sometimes when printing, the pages would come out in "random" order. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem occur and I found a solution…

When you look at the number of pages in the status bar in Word (bottom left corner) it reads something like: Page: 1 of 20 (or however many pages your document has in it).

Now go to your "Insert" Tab and look for the "Page Number" menu/button and drop it down to the "Format page numbers…"  In this dialog box, what does it read for "Page Numbering/Start at:" ?  If you have changed this setting to start at a new number, that is now the new page parameter set.

That should be the beginning of the print dialog box print range.

So say you have it set to "Start at: 9"  When you go to print the page range in the print dialog box your document is actually set now as Pages: 9-29 (instead of page 1-20).

If you only want to print the last ten pages you need to say print range "19-29".

Comment: Kind of a quirky workaround. Will have to wait until the situation comes up again to test it. Nice detective work, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same problem at the same time that I was having problems with my printer. When I ended up using some specific drivers for the printer (instead of the default/universal Apple printer driver) the problem went away. So if you are still struggling with this issue, I would suggest trying to use a printer specific driver. Hopefully that will resolve this issue for you.